# Windows Media Player not showing any songs

Tags: windows-media-player

I have just got a Windows Phone 8, and so I can put music on, I have started to use Windows Media Player. I had a small number of tracks on my computer initially (about 20 or so) which were added to the library as expected. I have just transferred all the songs I want (stored on another computer that is used as a media center), which is about 4700 songs, but now they are there, they are not existing in the library and cant be found at all, except for a few playlist files that exist, that show up under the Playlists branch of the navigation tree.

I have tried clearing the music library folders, restarting, and then setting the folders again as they should have been (to the folder "C:\users\cgoddard\music", which contains numerous subfolders of artists, albums, etc).

I have also tried deleting the entire directory "C:\Users\cgoddard\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player", which has been rebuilt, but to no avail.

Even dragging and dropping the folders (one by one, or all together) doesn't work. The only way I can get them to add is to individually select the mp3 files, and drag and drop them into the library, but considering the sheer number of folders, this will take a very long time.

Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of WMP and Windows are you using?

Comment: @TimDeBaets Version 12

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try rebuilding WMP's library once more by following these instructions. First note that resetting the library will make you lose all current play counts, and possibly ratings too. Then, follow these steps:

- Reboot the PC.
- Go to Start, type `services.msc` in the Search field, and press Enter. In Services, find the `Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service`. If its status is `Started`, double-click the service and click `Stop`.
- Go to Start, type `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft` in the Search field, and press Enter. This folder will open up in Windows Explorer.
- In this folder, delete the `Media Player` folder. If you can't see the folder, then it's probably hidden. Set Explorer to show hidden files and folders, and to show protected system files.
- Start WMP, your library will have been reset and will be rebuilt. Check if the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the Folder View of the Music Library and drag and drop your folder. If there are so many audio files, it will probably take a while updating.(WMP will probably not notify you that is doing any work, so you can first try adding only one subfolder to see if it will work with the whole folder).